# Carplay on Pi4 is not affected by screensaver?

Tags: screen-saver

Raspi4 running OpenautoPro. Using a working Carlinkit dongle for my Iphone.  That works fine.  The problem is that for some reason my screensaver runs behind the Carplay interface defeating the purpose of said screensaver.  I'm sure it's something simple, but so far can't pinpoint the cause.  Anyone?

Comment: `Anyone?` is not a question about the Raspberry Pi